# NodeJS fs and require looking in different places

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, fs

I am trying to loop through a directory and require every file in it. My code is working, but I was wondering why I had to modify the path in fs functions. (Code below stripped of useless info)

Folder structure:

```
project
|-- bin
|   `-- start
|-- modules
|   |-- file1.js
|   `-- file2.js
`-- package.json
```

/bin/start:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// Require dependencies
var fs = require('fs')

// Get modules
// NOTE: fs is looking in the project folder, but this file is in the bin folder
fs.readdir('./modules', function (err, files) {
  // Handle error
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    process.exit(1)
  }

  // Loop through files
  files.forEach(function (file, index) {
    // Get info about file
    fs.stat('./modules/' + file, function (err, stat) {
      // Handle error
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        process.exit(1)
      }

      // If it is a file
      if (stat.isFile()) {
        // NOTE: require is looking in the bin folder, and this file is in the bin folder
        require('../modules/' + file)
      }
    })
  })
})
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "modular-chat",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple modular example of a chat application",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/start"
  },
  "author": "JoshyRobot",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Comment: Good observation .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require` is a Node function. It's just that `require` uses `__dirname` as the basename when resolving relative paths rather than the current working directory which is also the result of `process.cwd()`.

You simply need to join `__dirname` to your relative paths before passing them to `fs` functions. Using  using `path.join(__dirname, '../modules')` and `path.join(__dirname, '../modules', file)`. Use these in your `fs.readdir` and `fs.stat` calls:

```
fs.readdir(path.join(__dirname, '../modules'), function (err, files) {

fs.stat(path.join(__dirname, '../modules', file), function (err, stat) {
```

This makes both your fs calls and the require align so that the right files are loaded.

---

It is also not that hard to do the reverse and make require load any path:

Rather than `require(path.join('../modules/', file))`:

```
require(path.join(process.cwd(), '../modules/', file))
```

This works because `require` doesn't change absolute paths as it does with  relative paths by prepending `__dirname`.

Comment: why use `fs.readdir(path.join(__dirname, '../modules')`, if `fs.readdir('../modules'` works as well? the code provided in the question `fs.readdir('./modules'` results in `not found` error

Comment: @Maximus No, the code I provided works fine, but the problem was that `fs.readdir(...)` and `require(...)` were looking in different places, which is why the `fs.readdir` call used the path `./modules` while the require used `../modules`. `fs.readdir('../modules'...)` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is `require('../modules/' + file)` is not a node function, it is common.js syntax. When you run `require`, it sees the file relative to the file in which the `require` function is run, and when you run the `fs` module, it executes relative to the node command.